# SSO/Oauth login on same application, Login based on UrL

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I have spring MVC application and I am trying to register different SSO login on same application. For example if url is (**admin.abc.com**), It should login from microsoft SSO and if the url is **abc.com** it should redirect to google login.
Here is my code but when I run the code both sso open with giving me the option to choose.
Is there any way I can set sso login based on domain instead of select option.

```
  @Autowired
    ClientRegistrationRepository regRepository;

@Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(Arrays.asList(msClientRegistration(), googleSSOClientRegistration()));
    }
```

and the configuration for antmatcher is like this

```
@Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http)
        throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login.htm").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/**")
            .permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(oauthLogoutSuccessHandler())
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .and().oauth2Login()
            .failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler())
            .authorizationEndpoint()
            .authorizationRequestResolver(
                new CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver(regRepository, "/oauth2/authorization"))
            .and().tokenEndpoint()
            .accessTokenResponseClient(authorizationCodeTokenResponseClient())
            .and().and().headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .sameOrigin().and().csrf()
            .disable();
    }
```

How to add antMatcher configuration based on domain url? google sso for abc.com and admin.abc.com for microsoft login with OAuth2.
[image: Instead of having this I want to redirect base on url's]

Instead of having this I want to redirect base on url's.. either Google login or Microsoft.

Comment: You might create a custom filter/resolver for both like adapters. I might help you but if you increase 200+, because take several minutes of my time. :c